# Why generic instance of some_class can't be initialized with generic instance of some_class subclass

Tags: c#, generics

The following line throws an error:

`SomeGenericClass<ClassA> genericInstance = new SomeGenericClass<ClassB>();`

The error says:
Cannot implicitly convert type 'SomeGenericClass<ClassB>' to 'SomeGenericClass<ClassA>'

```
public class SomeGenericClass<T>
{
    public T someField;
}

public class ClassA
{

}

public class ClassB : ClassA
{

}
```

So, why it doesn't work? Isn't it intended to cast it with ClassA like when `ClassA instance = new ClassB();` and is there any workaround?

Comment: Generic classes are invariant, therefore it doesn't work. You should use exactly the same type for declaration and assignment, not less of more derived. Have a look at [covariance and contravariance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance) for more information

Comment: Correct. `SomeGenericClass<T>` cannot be covariant in `T`. First of all, covariance in generics is supported only for `interface` and `delegate` types, not `class` types. Secondly, you have a public read _and_ write field of type `T` there, so the covariance would not be safe in this case (if we imagined that C# supported covariance for `class` types).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Promoted from a comment.)

`SomeGenericClass<T>` cannot be covariant in `T`.

First of all, covariance in generics is supported only for `interface` and `delegate` types, not `class` types.

Secondly, you have a public read *and* write field of type `T` there, so the covariance would not be safe in this case (if we imagined that C# supported covariance for `class` types).

What you *can* do, is this:

```
public interface ISomeGenericFace<out T>
{
    T SomeProperty { get; }
}

public class ClassA
{

}

public class ClassB : ClassA
{

}
```

Note: I use `interface` instead of `class`. I use the `out` modifier to achieve covariance in `T`. I make sure the member `SomeProperty` has "out" semantics, i.e. no `set` accessor.

Comment: I put that property jsut for no reason. But wow, that really helped. Thanks!